# Kotlin print issue with farenheit conversion

Tags: kotlin

I tried to print out:

> F degrees Fahrenheit = C degrees Celsius

and I can't get it to work I have tried so many things also be nice I'm new to coding.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  var F = "32";
  var C = (F - 32) * .5555556;
  var conversion = "F  degrees Fahrenheit = C degrees Celsius"
  println(conversion);
}
```

Comment: Nice question! But what sort of an issue do you encounter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [template string](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#using-string-templates):

```
fun main() {
    var f = 68.0;
    var c = (f - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;

    var conversion = "$f degrees Fahrenheit = $c degrees Celsius"

    println(conversion)
}
```

Other things to note:

- I've used a floating point number instead of a string for the `f` variable. This allows me to use floating point math to calculate the Celsius equivalent.
- I renamed the variables to be lowercase, as per the coding conventions.
- I replaced the `.5555556` literal with `5.0 / 9.0`. Better to introduce rounding errors later rather than earlier.
- Even though in this case it's sufficient to only explicitly turn the `f` variable into a floating point number to force floating point math to be used, it's probably safer to just apply the same logic to all numbers.

Comment: I would have used `32.0` `5.0` and `9.0` to ensure that all calculations are done as floating point operations, accidental integer divisions are so annoying.